# Rename multiple different files in SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, rename, filenames, file-rename

I'm looking to reduce filepath length due to various issues.

If I have two files in a folder, `folder_with_long_name/file A.txt` and `folder_with_long_name/file B.txt`. I want to change it to having `folder_short_name/fileA.txt` and `folder_short_name/fileB.txt`.

Currently, in order to rename these files and folders, I'd have to do 3 separate revisions, one for the folder, and one for each of the text files. Unlike other questions, I can't run a batch script, etc. to rename since there's no pattern to run on. It's a file-by-file, folder-by-folder rename.

I'd really like to be able to do this all in a single commit, to prevent 50+ different revisions.

If there's a way that I'm able to bundle this in with a regular commit as well, that would be even better. That would allow me to fix the filepath references in code at the same time, so that the code isn't broken during the renaming.

Comment: You should be able to do that in at most two commits. There's no limit to the number of files that can be changed in a commit. So rename all files first in one commit, then rename all directories in the next. You may be able to do it in one commit - rename the directories first, then the files, then commit (untested).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was trying to do this through the repo-browser of TortoiseSVN. Doing it there ends up with each renaming taking a separate revision. By checking out locally and making the renames through the tortoiseSVN menu item, I'm able to combine it into a natural commit. This also maintains the history of the file.